# How to combine arrays using array_combine in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have the Following Array's

```
Array
(
    [country] => Array
        (
            [0] => AF
            [1] => BS
            [2] => BR
            [3] => GB
            [4] => US
        )

    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://mu.com
            [1] => http://gov.com
            [2] => http://brazil.com
            [3] => http://uk.com
            [4] => http://usa.com
        )

)
Array=Array
```

The Array value is from the html form Post Method and the server side code is here

```
<?php 

$link[]=$_POST['url'];
$nation[] = $_POST['country'];
print_r($_POST);

$c=array_combine($link, $nation);
    foreach ($c as $link => $nation) {
        echo $link ."=".$nation;
    }
?>
```

I want to display  The following format using array_combine and foreach loop but i got Array=Array instead of below result.

```
http://mu.com = AF
http://gov.com = BS
http://Brazil.com = BR
```

Please Guide me the right way of doing this

Comment: Remove the square brackets `[]` from both assignments above. You're putting an array inside an array, that's why you get `Array=Array`.

Comment: It looks like `$link[]=$_POST['url'];` and `$nation[] = $_POST['country'];` are creating *arrays* named $link and $nation, and setting the first item of that array to the $_POST['url'] and $_POST['country'] values, both of which are also arrays.

Comment: Thanks Both of you Guys problem Solved :) My silly mistake.